# "Loi d'airain des salaires" comme la traduction de "Iron law of wages"

Tags: traduction, locutions, terminologie

J'ai appris récemment que le terme français pour la [*Iron law of wages*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_law_of_wages) est la [*Loi d'airain des salaires*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loi_d%27airain_des_salaires). *L'airain* étant une forme de cuivre (*bronze* en anglais), je me demande pourquoi l'autre métal a été utilisé dans la traduction (le cuivre pluôt que le fer.) Plus spécifiquement:  **s'agit-il de l'utilisation repandue dans des autres locutions françaises (que j'ignore) *ou* était-il ce terme utilisé à cause de la sonorité ressemblant au terme anglais (*iron*-> *airain*.)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Le concepteur de [Loi d'airain des salaires](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loi_d%27airain_des_salaires) est l'allemand [Ferdinand Lassalle](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferdinand_Lassalle#Th%C3%A9orie). Il a nommé le concept [Ehernes Lohngesetz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehernes_Lohngesetz), ce qui en français se traduit par  « Loi d'airain des salaires<sup>1</sup> ». Toute traduction de *Ehernes Lohngesetz* est forcément postérieure à son « invention » par Lassalle.

Il lui a donné ce nom parce que l'« airain » (terme vieilli et  désormais littéraire pour le bronze) est un alliage « très résistant utilisé pour la fonderie des cloches<sup>2</sup> ». Sauf erreur de ma part *ehern* était aussi déjà utilisé en allemand pour évoquer la dureté au sens figuré. Le [premier dictionnaire de l'Académie](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A1A0113) (1694) nous indique que le français utilisait déjà l'analogie avec l'airain pour évoquer la dureté, l'inexorabilité, il est donc tout à fait normal que la traduction française de *Ehernes (Lohn)gesetz* soit « loi d'airain (des salaires»).

À  noter que « de fer » était aussi [déjà utilisé](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=loi+d%27airain%2C+loi+de+fer&year_start=1780&year_end=2012&corpus=fr-2012&smoothing=3) en français pour évoquer la solidité au sens figuré. Mais autant on parlera plus volontiers « d'une volonté de fer » autant « [loi d'airain](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/loi_d%E2%80%99airain) » est une locution employée de nos jours  pour parler d'une « loi ou règle implacable à laquelle on ne saurait échapper », et pas seulement en économie. On trouve parfois « [loi de fer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=loi+d%27airain%2C+loi+de+fer&year_start=1780&year_end=2012&corpus=fr-2012&smoothing=3) », relativement rarement comparé à « loi d'airain ».

Je ne répondrai pas entièrement à la question puisque je ne saurais dire pourquoi en anglais seul le mot *[iron](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/iron#Adjective)* (le fer) est semble-t-il utilisé pour évoquer la dureté, l'inexorabilité.

**Edit**
From a [comment](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53136/loi-dairain-des-salaires-comme-la-traduction-de-iron-law-of-wages/53138?noredirect=1#comment111809_53138) by Peter Shor
In English, *bronze* is bronze and *laiton* is brass. So there isn't an exact translation into English — you'd have to pick one of the two words. And for the figurative meaning, the closest equivalent we have in English is *iron*.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> [Ehern](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ehern)  → en airin ; [Lohn](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Lohn) → le salaire ; [Gesetz](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gesetz) → loi</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> Source : la page [en français de wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferdinand_Lassalle#Th%C3%A9orie), il semble que la page en allemand ne donne pas ce renseignement.</sup>

Comment: Quand je mets "ein ehernes Gesetz" dans Google translate, il me donne "an iron law" en anglais et "une loi d'airain" en français. Mais "ehernes" seul me donne "iron" et "fer". Et en anglais, on ne parle pas de "brazen laws".

Comment: @PeterShor Je crois que c'est fer au sens figuré ("strong, inflexible") dont il est question ici, pas du métal (même si bien sûr le métal est à l'origine), ces expressions sont ancrées culturellement et de façon relativement ancienne et fer est aussi employé en français pour évoquer la dureté au sens figuré. Effectivement en anglais cette notion d'inexorabilité est rendu par *iron* pas par *bronze* (brazen), Les traducteurs en ligne ont leurs limites.

Comment: @PeterShor By the way I've been trying for an hour to find if English has the equivalent of *airain* and I just can't find it. So I've come to the conclusion it hadn't. But I'd really like it to be confirmed. If you knew... it would be great. I can of course ask on ELL.

Comment: It seems that [*airain* is bronze](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/airain.html)... even if one uses *l'âge du bronze* for the *bronze age*. Wikipedia says that [*bronze* and *airain* are synonimous](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airain)

Comment: @None: Let me revise my previous comment (which I've deleted). From [*Wikipédia*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airain): "[Airain] est notamment utilisé comme synonyme de bronze et de laiton." In English, *bronze* is *bronze* and *laiton* is *brass*. So there isn't an exact translation into English — you'd have to pick one of the two words. And for the figurative meaning, the closest equivalent we have in English is *iron*.

Comment: In English, we do have the doublet *brazen/made of brass*, where *brazen* is always used for the figurative meaning, whereas *brass* is usually used for anything made out of the metal (e.g., *a brazen act* but *a brass ring*.)

Comment: Airain = Bronze = copper + tin (cuivre+étain). Laiton = copper+zinc. L'expression *coeur d'airain* est employée depuis le 18ème siècle. Exemple dans un [livre de 1801](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/N%C3%A9ologie_ou_Vocabulaire_de_mots_nouveau/iojJoeB8pHIC?hl=fr&gbpv=0) : *CAPITALISTE. Ce mot n'est guère connu qu'à Paris. Il désigne un monstre de fortune, un homme au coeur d'airain, ...*

Comment: One more comment: historically, the English language did not differentiate between *bronze* (*bronze* en français) and *brass* (*laiton* en français). From the OED: "**brass:** a. *Historically:* The general name for all alloys of copper with tin or zinc (and occasionally other base metals). To distinguish alloys of copper and tin, the name *bronze* has subsequently been adopted (Johnson 1755–73 explains the new word *bronze* as ‘brass’)." (A side note: English borrowed the word *bronze* from French.)

Comment: So it seems quite possible that Old (and maybe Middle) French treated these metals like Middle English did, and *airain* historically meant both *bronze* and *brass*.

Comment: @PeterShor  [Ancien Français](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/airain) indeed.

Comment: Ce sens du mot *airain* n'est pas une invention de Lassalle. Le [Dictionnaire de l'Académie française](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie4/airain) donne le sens figuré « malheureux & dur », « dur & impitoyable ». L'airain n'est pas qu'un symbole de dureté, il y a une connotation clairement négative. Le fer aurait aussi eu une connotation négative, mais pas tout à fait la même (il est associé avant tout aux armes : le fer, c'est l'épée).

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' Voir 2e § de ma réponse, je donne le lien vers le dictionnaire de l'académie (ed. 1694). Par ailleurs ce que je qualifie d'« invention » de Lassalle c'est le concept de *Ehernes Lohngesetz*. Je ne dis pas non plus qu'il a inventé le sens du mot *ehern* ou celui de *airain*.

Answer (score 3):

Cela provient sans doute de la mythologie grecque. L'airain était alors considéré comme un métal "divin". Par exemple, les pieds d'airain de la biche de Cérynie lui conféraient une vitesse fantastique (Héraclès l'a attrapée, mais après un an de poursuite). Les taureaux aux pieds d'airain étaient d'autres animaux fantastiques qui aidèrent Jason dans sa quête de la toison d'or. Bref, même si l'airain est "matériellement" moins dur que le fer, il a une grande dimension symbolique de grande dureté.

Comment: Loi d'airin étant la traduction exacte du concept formulé par son « inventeur » cette réponse  explique peut-être pourquoi Lassalle a donné le nom de  *Ehernes Lohngesetz* a sa loi, mais pas pourquoi le français et l'anglais n'ont pas opté pour la même traduction !

Comment: Je conviens que votre réponse est plus détaillée que la mienne. Ceci dit, airain et bronze étant techniquement de parfaits synonymes (=alliage de cuivre et d'étain), je pense que l'on pouvait se demander pourquoi utiliser un terme et pas l'autre au moment de la traduction.

Comment: C'est avant la traduction que le choix entre un terme ([*ehern*](https://fr.pons.com/traduction/allemand-fran%C3%A7ais/ehern)) ou l'autre (*bronze)* a été fait,  la symbolique est la même dans les deux langues et la traduction est fidèle.